# installing ggplot for python on windows10 64

Tags: python, statsmodels, python-ggplot

I am using python 2.7 and installed the anaconda installations too.

although I am novice user, but everything is working fine.

Then I decided to use the ggplot. (yhat package for python)

instructions says 
`pip install -U ggplot`

I had problem that it started to install many packages including ggplot but then it halt during the statsmodels package giving the following message:

```
c:\Python27\Scripts>pip install -U ggplot
Collecting ggplot
  Using cached ggplot-0.6.8.tar.gz
Requirement already up-to-date: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from ggplot)
Collecting statsmodels (from ggplot)
  Using cached statsmodels-0.6.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-8ce3lv\statsmodels\setup.py", line 393, in <module>
        install_requires) = check_dependency_versions(min_versions)
      File "c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-8ce3lv\statsmodels\setup.py", line 119, in check_dependency_versions
        if not (StrictVersion(strip_rc(npversion)) >= min_versions['numpy']):
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 40, in __init__
        self.parse(vstring)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\version.py", line 107, in parse
        raise ValueError, "invalid version number '%s'" % vstring
    ValueError: invalid version number '1.10.0.post2'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-8ce3lv\statsmodels
```

I read in SO and on gitHub many questions but nothing is clear except that it is versioning problem

I tried to upgrade the packages but I failed.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use `conda install statsmodels`. works for me on Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

numpy 1.10 will soon be available without the `post` in the version number, based on the discussion on the numpy mailing list and numpy issue tracker.

The version scanning of statsmodels cannot handle the `post` part since it has never been used in the past by any science or data analysis related package.

The only solution right now is to edit the setup.py of statsmodels, or switch to a numpy version that doesn't have the `post` version number, or edit the version number in numpy.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2645
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6431

Comment: Would you please clarify how can i edit setup.py of statmodels? I'm afraid to break things whie editing

Comment: I ended up using the conda install and it worked perfectly with me . here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29314525/3404841