# Module ggplot installed but cannot be imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda, python-ggplot

I installed `ggplot` for python 2.7 in a Win64 env using `conda` via the command line:

```
$conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/bokeh ggplot
```

since:

```
$pip install -U ggplot
```

could not locate the package (see pevious [stackQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312985/cannot-install-ggplot-with-anaconda)).

Checking if module is installed:

```
 >python -c "import ggplot"
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: No module named ggplot
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

*Update notes*: debug tests

```
 $pip freeze  
 >(finds package ggplot)
 $import imp
 $imp.find_module("ggplot")
 >'C:\\Users\\Remi\\Anaconda2\\envs\\envx\\lib\\site-packages\\ggplot'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am posting the resolution I arrived to. It is not linear, although it may benefit others who may encounter a similar issue.

First step: activated the environment `envx` where the `ggplot` module was said to reside in.

Importing module again:

```
$python -c "import ggplot"
```

Throws a complaint ending with:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

among failures in requesting imports from `scipy` and `ggplot` modules.

Second step: re-installed `scipy`

```
$conda install scipy
```

Here conda has to do some 'intuitive' updates of `python`, `numpy` ... ect. During the initial `ggplot` install, `conda` went the downgrade route.

That's it.

Comment: Hey I'm seeing this same issue, though I'm not sure how to "activate the environment envx where the ggplot module was said to reside in."  How did you do that?  Thanks so much!