# Python yaml: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, yaml

I created a new environment in conda and installed there yaml.

```
$ conda list | grep yaml
yaml                      0.1.7                had09818_2
```

but I cannot import it:

```
$ python -c 'import yaml'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

Python points to the right directory with the env:

```
$ which python
/home/xxx/.conda/envs/tf2/bin/python
```

What can be the issue?

I checked similar questions: in 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693420/python-modulenotfounderror-but-module-is-installed) the problem was caused by bad disk sector, 
while in 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465839/module-ggplot-installed-but-cannot-be-imported) the single answer does not really explain anything.

My python is 3.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.04 if it matters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Conda package, `yaml`](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/yaml), is the C library for parsing YAML. [The Python library](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyyaml) goes by the name `pyyaml`.  So,

```
conda install pyyaml
```