# Can't install ggplot with anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, python-ggplot

(*I'm aware of this question [Cannot install ggplot with anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312985/cannot-install-ggplot-with-anaconda) but that is aimed at Windows, and I'm running a Linux OS*)

I'm attempting to install the `ggplot` package in a `python3` (v3.6.0) Anaconda environment:

```
$ conda install ggplot
Fetching package metadata .............


PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - ggplot

Close matches found; did you mean one of these?

    ggplot: r-ggplot2, r-gplots
```

If I use `conda search` I get:

```
$ conda search ggplot 
Fetching package metadata .............
r-ggplot2                    1.0.0                         0  defaults        
                             1.0.0                        0a  defaults        
                             1.0.1                  r3.2.2_0  defaults        
                             1.0.1                  r3.2.0_0  defaults        
                             1.0.1                  r3.2.1_0  defaults        
                             1.0.1                 r3.2.1_0a  defaults        
                             1.0.1                 r3.2.2_0a  defaults        
                             1.0.1                 r3.2.0_0a  defaults        
                             2.1.0                  r3.3.1_0  defaults        
                             2.2.0                  r3.3.1_0  defaults        
                             2.2.0                  r3.3.2_0  defaults
```

but if I search https://anaconda.org/search for `ggplot` I get [lots of results](https://anaconda.org/search?q=ggplot).

The questions: why am I not seeing those results when using `conda search`? What is the difference between `ggplot` and `r-ggplot2` (the package it offers to install when I search for `ggplot`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why am I not seeing those results when using `conda search`?

The difference for search is that `conda search` only searches in your channels, `anaconda search` or the search on anaconda.org includes **all** (public) channels. The name in front of the package name is the channel, for example `xyz/ggplot` the `xyz` is the channel.

> What is the difference between `ggplot` and `r-ggplot2`

It's probably a naming convention. `anaconda` has [several `R` based packages](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/r_language) and it's likely they seperate them using the `r-` prefix from more regular python packages. So if you don't plan to use it with "R" you should probably look for a suitable candidate without the `r-`.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes things much more clear.